# Expresso Store: List items on PayPal

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, ecommerce, paypal

How do I get Store to list individual items and their prices on PayPal? At the moment, the only information which is displayed on the PayPal site is the order number.

Thanks
Lee

Comment: Hi Lee, and welcome. To give you the best chance of getting the answer you need and to make it easier for people to help you get it, you're probably going to need to expand your question somewhat. Start with adding some more info about your setup, eg, ee + store versions, are you using Paypal Pro or standard? etc. The more information you give the more chance you'll get the answer you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start by saying that PayPal will take your order subtotal and tax rate and want to calculate the tax amount on their own. Normally that wouldn't be a problem but PayPal is notorious for rounding the values wrong which will cause the transaction to fail as their tax calculation is different then what is passed through via Store. So you need to make sure that you run though more test transactions then you normally would to make sure that the rounding issue is not a problem with your site.

**This is assuming that you are using Store 1.6.1:**

While this is not officially supported (I am not sure when or if it will become officially supported) it should do what you need. [CI Merchant GitHub Fork](https://github.com/guillermofr/ci-merchant/commit/70ea1a2864971078b3b67e5ca1051be174f23fa0) will be replacing the system/expressionengine/third_party/store/ci-merchant/libraries/merchant/merchant_paypal_base.php file with the one from the repo. From there you should be seeing your orders data being passed in.

Comment: Just to clarify - the tax rounding issue Justin refers to should only be a problem if you have "Round item prices after tax" enabled in Store (e.g. you display prices including tax on your front end).

Comment: Aww yes I should of mentioned that in my original post

Comment: Thanks guy's, I'll try out that file. Coming from a CartThrob background I'm used to seeing line items displayed in PayPal - I think customers like to see it as well. Gives them a last view on what they are buying before making the payment. Hope you'll consider making it officially supported.

Comment: +1 on additional order details in the paypal checkout process!