# How do I send item descriptions from Store to PayPal Express?

Tags: expresso-store, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-express-checkout

Please can anyone help, my EE Store is working fine and is sending the correct details to PayPal Express, however, is there any way I can send item descriptions too? At the moment, the PayPal descriptions area remains blank.

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the PayPal Express gateway files. There is another [thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/expresso-store-list-items-on-paypal) already that shows the steps involved.

After you have made the changes you should see the items being passed along to PayPal.