# Fatal Error in EE Control Panel after updating Expresso Store PayPal Express code

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, paypal-express-checkout

I am having some issues trying to pass checkout cart line items to PayPal Express as part of the checkout process. I tried editing the merchant_paypal_base.php file as instructed in the post [Expresso Store: List items on PayPal](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1079/expresso-store-list-items-on-paypal) but couldn't get it to work so reverted back to the original php file.

Now, when I enter the Control Panel as administrator and navigate to **Store > Settings > Payment Methods** the screen refuses to load and instead offers this error message (URL redacted).

"Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Merchant_paypal_base in /xxxx/system/expressionengine/third_party/store/ci-merchant/libraries/merchant/merchant_paypal_base.php on line 34"

I have tried logging out/in and clearing all caches but to no avail. I was kind of expecting the passing of PayPal item details to be included with Store, so am a little disappointed that it requires some hacking around to pass this information across and it's a little beyond me. Any help much appreciated to either fix the error or get the item information to pass across to PayPal successfully.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generally the payment gateway is just there to take the payment and provide confirmation of that payment in relation to that order. Order confirmation emails are completely customisable and should reflect the order details including line items, individual costs, taxes, shipping etc. Is there a particular reason you'd need it in the Paypal order confirmation and not Store's order confirmation?

Comment: I guess it's just what I've been used to from using e-commerce frameworks such as Magento. From a customer perspective, I always feel that taking people off-site to PayPal to enter payment details is expecting them to take a small leap of faith as they leave the comfort of the e-commerce site, and it'd just be nice to show that the exact details of their cart contents has been passed across, not just the order total. The site's customers won't necessarily be IT-savvy. I will certainly make use of a customised email order confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

It is going to be hard to diagnosis the issue since you have modified the files. The easiest thing to do would be to replace your store files with a fresh download to make sure that you have properly reverted your files.

Comment: Thank you Justin, and apologies for the delay in response. I'm taking this opportunity to upgrade to Store v2 (as a recent customer) and will report back as I delve further into the setup.